# Get the post/response on my twitter wall using `twitter4j`?

Tags: java, twitter, response, twitter4j

I have the follower. How do I get their `post` response on my Twitter wall using `twitter4j`?

```
  User u1 = null ;
  long cursor = -1;
  IDs ids;
  System.out.println("Listing followers's ids.");
  do {
          ids = twitter.getFollowersIDs("Elfrania1", cursor);
      for (long id : ids.getIDs()) {
          System.out.println(id);
          User user = twitter.showUser(id);
          System.out.println(user.getName());             
      }
  } while ((cursor = ids.getNextCursor()) != 0);
```